# move_uploaded_file to folder not working

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create an image uploader, but i am having trouble saving the image in a folder. Should the folder be in the root of my directory named images? and if so, how come it is not saving the images to that folder when i use  move_uploaded_file code?

Thank you.

```
//connect to db include('includes/connection.php');

if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
    }       
    $query="INSERT into store (`id`,`name`,`size`,`type`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
    $desired_dir="images/";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);      // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir($desired_dir.$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "$desired_dir/$file_name");
        }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir=$desired_dir.$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
     mysql_query($query);           
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}

echo '<img src="images/' . $row['id'] . '</img>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the chmod of the folder on 775

**Explanation chmod**

Chmod gives access rights to your folder or files.

**Where stands the charater for?**

> ```
> The first charater stands for user
> The second character stands for group
> The thirth character stands for world
> ```

**Rights**

> ```
> 0 No Permissions 
> 1 Execute Only 
> 2 Write Only 
> 3 Write & Execute Permissions
> 4 Read Only
> 5 Read & Execute Permissions
> 6 Read & Write Permissions
> 7 Read, Write & Execute Permissions
> ```

**How to change the chmod**

*Via filezilla*

1. make an connection to your ftp
2. search your folder
3. right click and select file permissions
4. Set numeric value on 775

*Via direct admin*

1. go to the file manager
2. search for your folder
3. Fill in "set permission" with the value 775
4. press the button.

*Via linux kernel*

1. start up the kernal
2. run chmod 7 7 5 myfolder/

Comment: While you are here, you wouldn't know how to display the uploaded image in the html would you?

Comment: In the example you gave the image name is stored in a database table called `store`. You should read the `name` cell out of this table and put it in an img tag: example `<img src="imagefolder/ '. $res["name"] .'" />`

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the folder and properties and ensure the permissions are set to read and write

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can correct it like this:

```
    $desired_dir="images";
    if(empty($errors)==true){
        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"images/".$file_name);
        }else{                                  //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_dir="images/".$file_name.time();
             rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
        }
    mysqli_query($conny, $sql);         
    }else{
            print_r($errors);
    }
}
```